# An implementation of a general solution of Abel's equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis

### Introduction

An Abel equation of the second kind in its canonical form is writen as

$$y(x)y'(x)-y(x)=f(x)\quad  (6)$$
for arbitrary $f(x)$. This equation has a general solution derived by [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk1v2.png) [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T2wh.png) (Check Wikipedia article for [Abel equation of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind), which in some cases reduces to the above form)

What I am trying to do is to solve the equation

$$y(x)y'(x)-y(x)=Ax^2  $$
over the reals with $A$ constant. This equation does not appear in the tabulated solutions of **Polyanin, Manzhirov**, so I tried to implement the method from the paper [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk1v2.png). However, I noticed that the solution does not agree with the numerics, so I tried to run my code on an equation that we know the solution to, which is:

$$y(x)y'(x)-y(x)=x  $$

The result is summarised below using the language of Mathematica. As we can see, the analytical plot does not belong to the solution family seen in the second picture.

### Goal

I am trying to write a code that would apply the method described in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk1v2.png) to solve the **general** Abel equation. The solution can be applied in **any** programming language.

### Method

[image]

### Code

```
(*Solving for y*)
ζ[x_] = Log[Abs[x + 2 λ]]
F[x_] = ζ[x]
G[ζ_] = 
1/16 ((ζ Sin[ζ] + Cos[ζ]) CosIntegral[ζ] + 
 Cos[ζ]^2)*(4 ζ CosIntegral[ζ] + 
  Cos[ζ] )/(ζ CosIntegral[ζ])^3 Exp[-ζ] - 
2 F[ζ]

a = -4;
b[ζ_] = 3 + 4 (G[ζ] + F[ζ]) Exp[-ζ]
c[ζ_] = - 4 (G[ζ] + 2 F[ζ]) Exp[-ζ]

p[ζ_] = -a^2/3 + b[ζ]
q[ζ_] = 2 (a/3)^3 - a b[ζ]/3 + c[ζ]
NN = Solve[Z^3 + p Z + q == 0, Z] /. {p -> p[ζ], 
 q -> q[ζ]} /. ζ -> ζ[x];
y = Table[
Table[1/2 (x + 2 λ) ((Z /. NN[[ii]]) + 1/3), {ii, 1, 
 3}], {λ, 1, 2}];

(*Benchmarking*)
DSolve[Y'[X] Y[X] - Y[X] == X, Y[X], X]

p1 = Plot[y, {x, 0, 10}]
p2 = Table[
ContourPlot[
1/10 ((5 + Sqrt[5]) Log[
      1 + Sqrt[5] - (2 Y)/X] - (-5 + Sqrt[5]) Log[-1 + Sqrt[5] + (
       2 Y)/X]) == II - Log[X], {X, 0, 10}, {Y, -10, 15}], {II, 0,
 3, 0.2}];
Show[p2]
```

### Plots

The plots look not alike

[image: New solution]

[image: Standard solution]

### References

1. Dimitrios E. Panayotounakos, "Exact analytic solutions of unsolvable classes of first and second"
   order nonlinear ODEs (Part I: Abel’s equations)
2. Panayotounakos, Dimitrios E.; Zarmpoutis, Theodoros I, "Construction of Exact Parametric or Closed Form Solutions of Some Unsolvable Classes of Nonlinear ODEs (Abel's Nonlinear ODEs of the First Kind and Relative Degenerate Equations)".

Comment: I started a discussion on this topic over ta mapleprime, but it led nowhere. The formulas as written by Panayotounakos do not agree numerically. Maybe there are typos, maybe there are errors, difficult to say. See: https://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/38740-Abel-ODEs-Were-Allegedly-Solved-In-2005, and more recently: https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/123656-Abel-Equations-And-D-Panayotounakos, https://www.mapleprimes.com/questions/230106-About-Abel-First-Order-ODEs-In-Maple. Also, see this, you may have better luck: https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1503/1503.05929.pdf